# Android : Two Different button calling two different class not working properly

Tags: android, android-intent

This is a very naive issue.
I want to call two different class from two different buttons.
The below code is working fine but the **GalleryView.class** is getting executed only for once.The moment i call the **SelectImage.class** which is a dialogue seems to be working fine but the other one showing up only once.Please throw some light on this.

Thanks & Regards
Avijit Paul

```
private Button button,button1;
public static String filename = "prefs";
SharedPreferences prefs;

public vp_default() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);   
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(filename,0);

        button  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.view_gallery_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        button1  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sel_image_button);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this); 

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
            String setPhnNo = "9231512345";
            boolean stat = prefs.contains(setPhnNo);

            switch(v.getId())
            {
             case R.id.view_gallery_button:     
                    if(stat!=false)
                    {

                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VirtualPainterActivity.class));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GalleryView.class));


                    }
                break;
                case R.id.sel_image_button: 
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SelectImage.class));

                break;
            }

    }
```

}

//manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mcc.vp.apps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".vp_default" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> 
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".VirtualPainterActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.vp_regn" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".GalleryView">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.vp_gview" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SelectImage" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".ViewImage">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.vp_view_img" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: what do u mean with "seems to be working fine but the other one showing up only once"... it has to show up more than once??

Comment: I mean to say that the onOnClickListener for view_gallery_button is executing atleast for once but the moment i go back to my main activity ,the OnClickListener is not working anymore.

Comment: do you get an error? or it just doesn't start? have you debugged to see if the onClick event is triggered?

Comment: No didnt get any error.Yes i have debugged it and checked it on emulator,the onClick event is getting executed only once at the view_gallery_button but the sel_image_button is getting executed evertime i click on it.

Comment: i was wondering why you are using stat!=false if you can use !stat .

Comment: @Akki I am checking a condition but even if you remove that ,the result is same.

Comment: @potupaul post you manifest and layout file i think something in there which is causing the problem

Comment: remove <action android:name="android.intent.action.vp_gview" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
these two line of codes from manifest from all the activity except the main activity

Comment: you change the value of stat??? and use if(stat) insted of(stat!=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finnally solved it...The Problem was in the manifest file..i have declared "action.MAIN" twice..and the button keeps on iterating the default activity...anywz thanks to everyone for their time.... @Perroloco @Akki @Zaz Gmy

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the error is, but thry the following:

put the listener directly in the onCreate method like this

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
    YOUR CODE FOR BUTTON 1
    }


});
```

And do the same for button ;)

Comment: I did try the above code but its the still the same.Please note there is no error in any of the codes given above.Two buttons calling two different activity.One of them is executing whenever clicked but the other is getting executed only at once.

Comment: ok this is just for testing, but try setting the onclicklistener in the onResume method.

Comment: what am i suppose to write in onResume method ???...I have no idea how click listener works on that.

Comment: ok, in your activity, move the code button.setOnClickListener(new Oncl...) into the onResume method...thats all!